# C# script accessing previously compiled methods

Tags: c#, mono

I'm looking to move a scripting solution that I currently have over to C# as I believe as this will solve some of the issues which I am currently facing when it comes to running on different platforms. I can call functions which are within the script and access their variables, however, one thing that I would like to be able to do is call a function from the class that the script resides in. Does anyone know how I would be able to do this?

Here is my code at the minute which is working for calling and access objects within the script, but I would like to be able to call the method "Called" from within the script, but cannot:

```
using System;
using System.CodeDom.Compiler;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.CSharp;

namespace scriptingTest
{
    class MainClass
    {
        public static void Main (string[] args)
        {
            var csc = new CSharpCodeProvider ();

            var res = csc.CompileAssemblyFromSource (
                new CompilerParameters ()
                {
                    GenerateInMemory = true
                },
                @"using System; 
                    public class TestClass
                    { 
                        public int testvar = 5;
                        public string Execute() 
                        { 
                            return ""Executed."";
                        }
                    }"
            );

            if (res.Errors.Count == 0) {
                var type = res.CompiledAssembly.GetType ("TestClass");
                var obj = Activator.CreateInstance (type);
                var output = type.GetMethod ("Execute").Invoke (obj, new object[] { });
                Console.WriteLine (output.ToString ());

                FieldInfo test = type.GetField ("testvar");
                Console.WriteLine (type.GetField ("testvar").GetValue (obj));
            } else {
                foreach (var error in res.Errors)
                    Console.WriteLine(error.ToString());
            }
            Console.ReadLine ();
        }

        static void Called() // This is what I would like to be able to call
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Called from script.");
        }
    }
}
```

I am attempting to do this in Mono, however, I don't believe this should affect how this would be resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a handful of things you need to change.

`MainClass` and `Called` need to be accessible to other assemblies so make them `public`. Additionally, you need to add a reference to the current assembly to be able to access it in your script code. So essentially your code will end up looking like:

`public class MainClass`

`public static void Called()`

```
var csc = new CSharpCodeProvider();
var ca = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
var cp = new CompilerParameters();

cp.GenerateInMemory = true;
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("System.dll");
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add("mscorlib.dll");
cp.ReferencedAssemblies.Add(ca.Location);

var res = csc.CompileAssemblyFromSource(
    cp,
    @"using System; 
        public class TestClass
        { 
            public int testvar = 5;
            public string Execute() 
            { 
                scriptingTest.MainClass.Called();
                return ""Executed."";
            }
        }"
);
```

The output of running the test looks like:

Called from script.
Executed.
5

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, that worked perfectly. I had completely forgotten to flag the class and function as public, but I had no idea about adding the ReferencedAssemblies like this.